# Codigo en python no da el resultado esperado

Tags: python

No imprime el texto que ingreso por teclado, ¿Qué problema ven en este código?

```
def saludar():
    nombre = input("Ingresa tu nombre: ")
    return "Hola " + nombre + "!"
saludar()
```

Comment: hola, no se ve el código. el pantallazo se muestra muy pequeño. Por favor, copia y pega el texto en la pregunta.

Comment: gracias por el consejo! ya esta hecho

Comment: Tiene toda la pinta de que estás usando python 2.7 en lugar de python 3.x. Acabo de escribir eso mismo en un interprete de python y funciona sin problemas.

Comment: @Zumikya el prolema es que no estas imprimiendo nada, simplemente en tu última línea has esto `print(saludar())`, es decir tu función retorna algo un valor, pero cuando la invocas no hay ninguna instrucción que dicte mostrar el resultado en pantalla, prueba como te digo y debería funcionar

Comment: Efectivamente. Yo ví el resultado porque lo ejecuté directamente en el interprete.

Comment: Cuando agregué el print(saludar()) funcionó, pero por qué es necesario agregar eso si ya hay un return? No me queda muy claro cuando poner return y cuando print

Comment: el return no va a imprimir nada, solo le esta diciendo a la función que del proceso que tiene por dentro de su contexto regrese el resultado de ello que puede estar contenido por ejemplo en una variable, es decir que *hable* y *diga* que tiene lo cual se podrá imprimir en la pantalla con una instrucción que saque ese dato y lo muestre en la pantalla @Zumikya

Comment: Clarísimo! Gracias a los dos!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Si estas creando un método que retorna un texto y lo concatena con un valor que ingresa el usuario, usa la función [print()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) para imprimir la cadena con el nombre que ingresas:

```
def saludar():
    nombre = input("Ingresa tu nombre: ")
    return "Hola " + nombre + "!"

print(saludar())
```

Ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

> ¿por qué es necesario agregar eso si ya hay un return?

En realidad la función que realizas, únicamente es llamada, realiza un proceso, pero esta no realiza la impresión del texto.

Si deseas que tu función imprima el texto, puedes usar la función `print()` dentro de tu función `saludar()` de esta forma:

```
def saludar():
    nombre = input("Ingresa tu nombre: ")
    print("Hola " + nombre + "!")

saludar()
```

Answer (score 0):

Para lo que buscas puedes hacer un print en la función en lugar de usar un return

```
def saludar():
    nombre = input("Ingresa tu nombre: ")
    print( "Hola " , nombre , "!")
saludar()
```

Comment: Saludos @JuanFelipeGrueso, en que se diferencia tu respuesta a la ya realizada por @Jorgesys??